# Ionic 2: FileTransfer upload windows 10 mobile fails, works on iOS and Android

Tags: cordova, upload, ionic2, file-transfer, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to upload a local file to AWS S3 on a windows 10 phone.  The code I'm using works fine for Android and iOS (using ionic-native wrapper here https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/transfer/):

```
  fileTransfer.upload(pathToFile, s3Url, options)
   .then((data) => {
     // blah bah
   }, (err) => {
     // error, poop.
   })
```

...but **fails** on Windows with this error:

```
    {"code":3,
    "source":"C:/Data/Users/DefApps/AppData/Local/Packages/com.rareprominence.addvideo2_h35559jr9hy9m/LocalState/cameraCaptureVideo.mp4",  
    "target":"https://add-video-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/",  
    "http_status":null,
    "body":null,
    "exception":null}
```

I literally just took the video before trying to upload, so I know it exists.

**Q) Is this a problem with Windows 10 mobile and SSL? Is there something extra I need to do to allow uploads over HTTPS?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, downloading the AWS cert should be the same as any other HTTPS endpoint.

To outline the steps (from memory):

You're getting AWS's certificate and copying it to an app-local folder.  Then you reference that certificate in the app manifest.  Finally, also include the endpoint URL (which should have the same domain as the certificate) in the app manifest.

I'll copy (and edit) the details from the Ionic forum post:

Win phone aps require a locally-stored certificate to access resources over SSL.

Download the certificate from the server: do it via browser, just hit the URL in question and click on the  padlock or similar in the URL bar (it's different for each browser, or you can do it via openssl in the command line).

e.g. in Firefox 54 Developer edition, visit the url (https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) then click the green padlock in the URL bar.  Click the right arrow to expand the details. Then click the 'more information' link which will bring up the security tab of the Page Info.  Choose 'view certificate' then go to the details tab and choose 'export'.  You can choose the export format in the dialogue (this is where you choose DER).

Then save as DER type - which has .cer extension for some reason. Save cert to project root e.g. 'aws-api-certificate.cer'

add the following to package.windows10..appxmanifest

```
<Extensions>
    <!--Certificates Extension-->
    <Extension Category="windows.certificates">
        <Certificates>
            <Certificate StoreName="Root" Content="aws-api-certificate.cer" />        
        </Certificates>
    </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

If required, additional certs could be added via this method (I guess).

Ensure to include the .cer in the project, as it will need to be included in the built package.

Make sure to include the AWS endpoint URL in your Win 10 project's list of endpoints.  Again, from the forum post:

> Make sure the win 10 project's appxmanifest file contains a content
>   URI for the data API:
>
> https://api.example.com8 (Rule: include and WinRT: all)
>
> Copy the api-certificate.cer file into the platform > windows folder
>   (or use the ./reload-platform windows powershell script).

It's been several months since I did this, so apologies if anything  has changed (in theory, it shouldn't, but theory is great, in theory).  Good luck :)

Comment: hey thanks, the issue is i literally can't see a way to download a certificate? Is it a specific browser thing that allowed you to do it, like IE vs Chrome vs Firefox etc?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the answer for Firefox Dev Edition (54).  Both Chrome and IE Edge have made it more difficult to export certs for some reason...

Comment: So thanks for this.  Have done all the necessary steps and triple checked, getting the same error.  So it must be something other than the SSL causing the issue.  Thanks, will mark as answer as it's helpful.